# clock in and clock out system

Tags: excel

hi there im creating a spreadsheet to use for clocking in and out of work and have a simple wee GUI set up already. along with this i have the current time showing as soon as i start up the worksheet but it shows on every page i was wondering how to stop this?? sample code below:
Global clockOn As Boolean

```
Sub runClock()
Range("M15").Value = Now()
If clockOn = True Then
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "runClock"
End If
End Sub

Sub Auto_Open()
clockOn = True
runClock
End Sub


Sub stopClock()
clockOn = False
End Sub
```

on top of this i will be doing a macro to put the information onto a specific page all going well as this will be depending on the day selected from the drop down menu any help with this would be greatly appriciated :) as in maybe an if statement in the VBA code to select the correct page and leave the data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the sheet that you are putting the value on; currently you only specify the range, but you don't specify the sheet. Can be done multiple ways, such as:

```
Sheets(1).Range("M15").Value = Now()
```

This selects the first sheet in the workbook. If you have multiple workbooks, you will need to specify that somehow as well (by referring to the active workbook, or the name of a workbook, etc.). For example:

```
Activeworkbook.sheets(1).Range("M15").Value = Now()
```